# How many potatoes and jerry cans needed in stranded deep?

Tags: stranded-deep

I am about to complete stranded deep. But I want to know that how many potatoes and jerry can are required in total just for story mode. I just need fuel for aeroplane. Also I want to know if the crate glitch works in stranded deep. I read on reddit that if we drop crate, save game and then open it and if we dont like the items we can reload to the last checkpoint to open crate again for other random things. Does that work?

Comment: Welcome to arqade! Your question is allright, but just one thing: If you ask for 2 different things, create 2 questions. So the crate glitch part should probably be within a 2nd question. Except that, welcome to the community!

Comment: @Fredy31 I m sorry for that, I wont repeat that. But can u answer for this time

Comment: Sadly, I do not know anything about stranded deep. Just giving you some guidelines. Good luck!